# Postgres copy command to load a zip file into database

Tags: php, postgresql, copy

I have a program that produces zip files and I save these temporarily in a directory like this:

```
  1.zip
  2.zip
  3.zip
  ...
```

I did a PHP program to load each of these files into a Postgres database but I need to do this with the command Postgres "copy" (because probably is faster)

I searched but I could not find the answer

So my table is like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE files (
  id int,
  file bytea,
  primary key (id));
```

So each file name is the "id" column and each zip file will be in "file" field

So how can i do this with a copy command?

Thank you all!

Comment: this is a horrible idea, why would you want to store zip files in the database? there is a name for a database explicitly made with the intent of storing files... A "filesystem".

Comment: @EvanCarroll How can i do a filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

[COPY ... WITH BINARY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) has some limitation on the supported binary format and I'm not sure it works with zip files.  If you're open to `INSERT`, I would suggest using [pg_read_file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE-TABLE), like:

```
INSERT INTO files VALUES
(1, pg_read_file('/path/to/1.zip')::bytea),
(2, pg_read_file('/path/to/2.zip')::bytea),
...
;
```

Comment: Thank you but my problem is that i have 2 millions files so how can i do this faster?

Comment: and i'm getting this error ERROR:  could not stat file "1.zip": No such file or directory

Comment: Given the volume you probably should explore using `COPY ... WITH BINARY` then.  Better yet, if possible, store only the file paths in the table in which case it would be a trivial `COPY`.  For `pg_read_file`, it's a server-side admin function, so you need to run as PostgreSQL admin user, and the target files need to reside under `data_directory`.  They could also reside somewhere else with symbolic link from `data_directory` (Be cautioned about potential security risks though).

Comment: so i came to the conclusion that is best to save file paths in database with copy command. But i can not find a good tutorial to explain me the process. The files can be anywhere? I just have to save the file path? How then can i download those files? What column type should i have to save the file paths? Text? Thank you very much

Comment: You can store a file path string in a column of type, say, CHARACTER VARYING(250).  Assuming you're using PHP (as your question was tagged), the actual files can be stored anywhere on a filesystem as long as your server-side PHP app has at least read access to the files.